# flask return pil generate image error, I can see the resize pictures but the response image is error

Tags: image, flask, file-io, python-imaging-library

I have flask api response picture:

```
FORMAT = {'image/jpeg':'JPEG', 'image/bmp':'BMP', 'image/png':'PNG', 'image/gif': 'GIF'}

@app.route('/api/image/<id>/<str_size>', methods=['get'])
def show_thumbnail(id, str_size):
    size = int(str_size)
    with get_db().cursor() as cur:
        cur.callproc('getimage', (id,))
        result = cur.fetchone()
        buf = BytesIO(result[1])
        if(size>0):
            im = Image.open(buf)
            im.thumbnail((size, size))
            buf = BytesIO(b'')
            im.save(buf, format=FORMAT[result[0].lower()])
        fw = open('w03.jpg', 'wb')
        fw.write(buf.getbuffer())
        fw.close()
        resp = Response(buf)
        resp.headers.set('Content-Type', result[0].lower())
    return resp
```

ps:

result[0] = 'image/jpeg'

result[1] is the bytes array of jpeg picture.

If I set the size(str_size) = 0, I mean I do not run PIL Image thumbnail code part. I can get the correct picture in response.

If I set the size(str_size) = 256 for instance, I find the 'w03.jpg' is correct and I can get the correct resize image, but the response is black for the reason is the image contains error.

Comment: If `result[0]` is `image/jpeg`, you mustn't pass that to `im.save()`'s `format` parameter. That should be `jpg`, not `image/jpeg`.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I give the format directly. if im.save() without format, it depending on extension name. If the format is given, it depends on format I use the FORMAT dictionary directly to give the format 'JPEG'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`im.save(buf)` puts the buffer to the end.  You need to rewind this before building `resp`  Do this with `buf.seek(0)`.  I *suspect* `buf.getbuffer` doesn't change the stream position in the same way, which would explain why `w03.jpg` is correct in the second test:

You can also use a `with` block to minimize some of the code (this auto closes the file):

```
        # ...
        with open('w03.jpg', 'wb') as fw:
            fw.write(buf.getbuffer())

        buf.seek(0)
        resp = Response(buf)
        # ...
```